# Tried Installing Homebrew but run wrong wrong file path

Tags: xcode, macos, terminal, path, homebrew

Tried installing hebrew but it seems i run the wrong file path when i got to the last step. now anytime i open terminal, this is how it appears and i get the "no such file or directory" error below.

```
Last login: Thu Jul  6 15:50:23 on ttys003
/Users/eugeniakwara/.zprofile:1: no such file or directory: /opt/homebrew/bin/brew
/Users/eugeniakwara/.zprofile:2: no such file or directory: /opt/homebrew/bin/brew
```

I am able to run homebrew after 'echoING' the right path and also able to run other commands. I want help in removing the error message so it does not appear anytime I open the terminal.

I want it to appear like this, without the error messages.

```
Last login: Thu Jul  6 15:50:23 on ttys003
eugeniakwara@NiBook-Air ~ %
```

I am using MacOS 10.15